# Entire hard disk is not shown

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu recently and while installing I partitioned harddrive into 2. One with size 70gb where  I installed UBUNTU and other with 180 gb. I'm not seeing 180gb partition in OS now. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu will show it's own partition only. You can still access your other partition (Windows, I am assuming) by opening file manager (search in dash for files or nautilus) and clicking on the disk icon on the left side, which carries the name or id of your hard drive

In the screenshot bellow (the red square is totally unrelated to the answer, by the way) you see this user have 4 other partitions in addition to "File system", which is actually Ubuntu partition

[image]

In addition, you can list all the partitions on your drive with these commands: `lsblk`, `sudo parted --list`, and `sudo fdisks -l`. The first one will show partitions as block devices with specific numeric id. Typically your whole drive is called `/dev/sda` and partitions are numbered `/dev/sda1,/dev/sda2,/dev/sda3 . . ./dev/sdaX`, you can recognize partitions by size. As for `parted --list` it's a little more detailed, and it will actually tell  you if a partition belongs to windows type of file system or not(it will say NTFS).

Comment: Like my answer ? leave upvote. Solved your problem ? accept the answer by clicking gray checkmark on the left side